# Expose property from Android module to ReactNative

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, kotlin

I am writing Android native module for ReactNative. I exposed some methods using `ReactMethod` annotation. Is there any possibility to expose property, e.g:

```
class MyNativeModule(reactAppContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactAppContext) {
    override fun getName(): String = "MyNativeModule"

    @ReactMethod
    fun nativeModule() {
        Log.d("MyNativeModule", "Native module method")
    }

    val nativeModuleProperty = "I am a native property" <-- I want to expose this property

}
```

And use it in ReactNative:

```
export const { nativeModule, nativeModuleProperty } = NativeModules.MyNativeModule
nativeModule() <-- this will print "Native module method"
console.log(nativeModuleProperty) <-- I want this to print "I am a native property"
```

How can I achieve that? Is it possible on Android?

Answer (score 0):

In *Kotlin* a `val` property is technically a getter method. So just annotate the getter instead of the property.

```
@get:[ReactMethod JvmName("nativeModuleProperty")]
val nativeModuleProperty = "I am a native property"
```

Comment: But I still have to call method `getNativeModuleProperty()` in React, not `nativeModuleProperty`

Comment: That's the default name of the getter. With `@JvmName("name")` you can rename it on _Java_.